# Получаю ошибку net :: ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME, когда нажимаю на geo ссылку сайта который открывается через webview flutter

Tags: android, flutter, webview, dart

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' ;
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(      
        body: WebView(
          initialUrl: "http://212.80.206.193/test.project-270.com/",
          
          debuggingEnabled: true,
          onWebViewCreated: (c) {
                var _webviewController = c;
                _webviewController.clearCache();
              },
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          
          ) ,
          
      ),

    );
    
  }
  
}
```

Ссылка geo на сайте

```
 <a class="navigation-kiosk" rel="nofollow" href="geo:{{$key->latitude}}, {{$key->longitude}}">@lang('main.geo_kiosk')</a>
```

Помогите решить проблему!

Comment: Проблема решена, кому нужно, вот рабочий вариант!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65880593/how-to-allow-mailto-schemes-in-webview-flutter

Comment: оформите ваш ответ (приложите код и комментарии) и отметьте его как решённым. Это поможет в будущем другим людям которые встретили такую-же проблему получить ответ на решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' ;
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(      
        body: WebView(
          initialUrl: "http://212.80.206.193/test.project-270.com/",
          
          debuggingEnabled: true,
          onWebViewCreated: (c) {
                var _webviewController = c;
                _webviewController.clearCache();
              },
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
             print(request.url);
             if (request.url.contains("geo:")) {
                launch(request.url);
                return NavigationDecision.prevent;
             } else {
                return NavigationDecision.navigate;
             }
          },
          ) ,
          
      ),

    );
    
  }
  
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]